# iOS Today Widget control background music app

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget, ios10-today-widget

I have a music streaming app for iOS and I am writing a Today Widget for it to offer similar functionality to the Apple Music app's Today Widget.

I have written the widget and am able to interact with it's UI to launch my app via a URL scheme and pass data over.

The difference between my widget and the Apple Music widget is that the Apple one sets the music off in the background, whereas my widget launches my streaming app as the foreground app.

Is it possible to launch a (or control an already launched) app into the background from the widget?